# Order Confirmation Email ends up in the SPAM folder

Tags: order-email, order-confirmation

Magento 1.9.1
Sendgrid free version

We use the Sendgrid free version to send out the Confirmation Emails to customers...it worked great but now it seems many people get the Confirmation Email in their SPAM folder. I checked with the hosting company and we are not blacklisted anywhere. What can we do to change this?

Shall we change the FROM Email address? (It comes from sales@.... now) or the Subject line? Would upgrading Sendgrid to the paid version help?

Comment: Have you set up SPF records for your domain?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try sending a Magento order conformation directly to the email address listed on https://www.mail-tester.com/?

Mail tester will analyse the results and rate your email from 1 to 10 (with 1 being the worst). Can you edit your question with the found issues, so we can see if they are Magento related?